# Formula Pressure Exerted by a Moving Fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

If I have a stream of moving fluid (moving at a velocity of $v$) flowing past a plate, is there a formula that calculates the pressure exerted by the fluid as a result of the **movement** of the fluid? More specifically, what is the difference in pressure if the fluid is static and moving?

I found a concept called dynamic pressure - but it doesn't seem to fit in this situation. By Bernoulli's principle, the faster the fluid the lower the pressure should be, but dynamic pressure was given as $q\propto v^2$, which is the opposite of what Bernoulli's principle states.

So my question is, is there a formula (as a function of $v$) for the pressure exerted specifically by the **motion** of a fluid on an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bernoulli's principle states that the following expression is a constant
$$\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2 + \rho g z + p = \mathrm{const}$$
From this equation you can evaluate the pressure reduction of a moving fluid.

**Example:** If you know the pressure $p_0$ of the fluid at rest and assuming there is no hight difference, $z=\mathrm{const}$ you get
$$p_0 = \frac{1}{2}\rho v^2 + p$$
or
$$p = p_0 - \frac{1}{2}\rho v^2$$